# Best way to get city, state and country from an address

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, google-api-php-client

I have random location data that I would like to get a city, state and country for.

Some of the fields have valid city, state, country, and some just a city, some a state and some other random address data.

Which free or close to it, would you recommend I use?

Answer (score 0):

I use Google MAPS API for this, as example , if i have an address, i can get all information I need, City, or coordinates:

```
`getCoords(context){
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    var r=geocoder.geocode({'address':context.page.position_text},function(a,b){
        context.setPlace(a[0])
    })
},`
```